# Помогите с jQuery show/hide

Tags: jquery, hide

Пытаюсь сделать что бы при наведении на блок показывалась картинка внутри него, таких блоков много, у меня при наведении на 1 блок картинки появляются во всех. Я так понимаю нужно сделать как то через this но у меня не получается

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".hover").show();
    });

    $(".card").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".hover").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: `.card:hover .hover { display: block; }` — Строчка CSS вместо всего этого кода)

Comment: спасибо) сработало

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $('.hover').hide();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".card").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).children('.hover').show();
        });

        $(".card").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).children('.hover').hide();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">Пурум
    <div class="hover">Пум Пум </div></div>
<div class="card">Пурум
    <div class="hover">Пум Пум </div></div>
<div class="card">Пурум
    <div class="hover">Пум Пум </div></div>
<div class="card">Пурум
    <div class="hover">Пум Пум </div></div>
```